# nodeJS : Route not working Restful API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, routes

I'm trying to build an API with node js /express, I have a problem with routing, I cannot get the right route when using express.Router(), here is my code :

this is the server.js file :

```
//
// ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── I ──────────
//   :::::: G E T   T H E   P A C K A G E   W E   N E E D : :  :   :    :     :        :          :
// ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('./config'); // get our config file
var User = require('./app/models/User'); // get our mongoose model
var users = require('./app/routes/users')
var routes = express.Router();

//
// ─── CONFIGURATION ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//

var port = process.env.PORT || 8000; // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
mongoose.connect(config.database, { useMongoClient: true }); // connect to database
app.set('superSecret', config.secret); // secret variable

//
// ─── USE BODY PARSER SO WE CAN GET INFO FROM POST AND/OR URL PARAMETERS ────────────────
//


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//
// ─── USE MORGAN TO LOG REQUESTS TO THE CONSOLE: ────────────────
//

app.use(morgan('dev'));

//
// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────── V ──────────
//   :::::: R O U T E S : :  :   :    :     :        :          :
// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//
// ─── BASIC ROUTES──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
app.get('/app', function(req, res) {
    res.json('Hello! The API is at http://localhost:' + port);
});

// ─── API USER ROUTES──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
app.use('/api', users);


// route to show a random message (GET http://localhost:8080/api/)
routes.get('/api/v1', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'Welcome to the coolest API on earth!' });
});

//
// ─── MIDDLEWARE ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//
routes.use(function(req, res, next) {

    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // decode token
    if (token) {

        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });

    } else {

        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        return res.status(403).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'No token provided.'
        });

    }
});
//
// ────────────────────────────────────────────────── VI ──────────
//   :::::: S T A R T the server: :  :   :    :     :        :          :
// ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens at http://localhost:' + port);
```

this rout not working I dont know what's the problem with that :

> routes.get('/api/v1', function(req, res) {
>   res.json({ message: 'Welcome to the coolest API on earth!' }); 
>   });

I'm trying to separate the user's route for authentication and signUp, here is the code of user routes :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('../../config'); // get our config file
var User = require('../../app/models/User'); // get our mongoose model
// ─── GET an instance of the router for api routes ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
var apiRoutes = express.Router();



apiRoutes.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
        res.json({ success: false, msg: 'set up required fields' });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        // save the user
        newUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.json({ success: false, msg: 'Username already exists.' });

            }
            res.json({ success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.' });
        });
    }
});

apiRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!user) {
            res.send({ success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
        } else {
            // check if password matches
            user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {
                if (isMatch && !err) {
                    // if user is found and password is right create a token
                    var token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret);
                    // return the information including token as JSON
                    res.json({
                        success: true,
                        token: token,
                        username: user.username
                    });
                } else {
                    res.send({ success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

apiRoutes.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    User.find({}, function(err, users) {
        res.json(users);
    });
});
module.exports = apiRoutes;
```

[image]
any one can help please ?

Comment: You might got the answer by now, Otherwise, in the postman client you need to use http://localhost:8000/api/api/v1 then it works, otherwise change the routes.get('api/v1', fn{}) to routes.get('v1') so that your call to api/v1 in postman gets response. Basically, once you declare the route 'api' to users, it does not require to use in the methods like get,post,put,delete etc, just the respective route names are enough like 'v1' or 'v2' etc without prefixing '/api'

Answer (score 0):

You register the `/api` route before the `/api/v1` route.

```
app.use('/api', users);


// route to show a random message (GET http://localhost:8080/api/)
routes.get('/api/v1', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'Welcome to the coolest API on earth!' });
});
```

Should be

```
// route to show a random message (GET http://localhost:8080/api/)
routes.get('/api/v1', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'Welcome to the coolest API on earth!' });
});

app.use('/api', users);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I get the same error : cannot get /api/v1 !!